# Pokemon go can't detect camera orientation

Tags: pokemon-go

I know the reason I can't see Pokemon in AR mode is because I don't have a gyroscope on my phone. Anyway I don't really know much about gyroscope sensors or anything but what I really want to know is can this be something they can fix in the future with an update? Will I be able to see Pokemon in the future in AR mode even if my phone doesn't have a gyroscope or will I just have to get a new phone?

Comment: have you tried turning off the AR option when encountering a pokemon? Just curious if that would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The gyroscope is likely used to detect the orientation of the phone, to angle the pokemon in such a way that it is touching the surface that is the floor, and that it is displayed at the right angle.

It is fairly unlikely that they will roll out an update that introduces an algorithm that will calculate this in real-time, on every phone, without gyroscope information, for every conceivable situation. It's a hard problem.